# How to make SEO friendly URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make this URL 
 
https://www.maxelplus.com/single-commercial.php?PId=Mjc&Title=Domestic%20Products 
to 
https://www.maxelplus.com/domestic-products/table-top-wet-grinders/sleek-table-top-wet-grinder-2l-LEP883/

I used below code but is not working.

RewriteRule ^domestic-products/table-top-wet-grinders/sleek-table-top-wet-grinder-2l-LEP883/$ single-commercial.php?PId=$1&title=$2 [QSA]

Please share whate i am missing..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your website is being hosted, it might be helpful to look at the .htaccess permalink structure [which can be found here](https://perishablepress.com/the-htaccess-rules-for-all-wordpress-permalinks/).

It looks like your first link is using a **custom structure** permalink, but your desired URL is a combination between **post name** and **product number**. A generic set of instructions [can be found here](https://yoast.com/help/how-do-i-change-the-permalink-structure/) if you are using WordPress. This can also clarify the benefits of using URLs that are friendly for Search Engine Optimization (SEO).